# How to pass a variable from model to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I pass a variable from the model to the controller?

Here is my model:

```
public function edititem($id){
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tblitem WHERE item_id = "$id"');

foreach ($query->result() as $row){
    $name = $row->item_name;
    $description = $row->item_description;
    $price = $row->item_price;

}
```

And here is my controller

```
public function editItem(){
      $this->load->helper('form');
      $this->load->model('ItemModel');
      $this->ItemModel->edititem($this->input->get('id'));

      $name = $this->input->post('name');
      $description = $this->input->post('description');
      $price = $this->input->post('price');

      $data['items'] = $this->ItemModel->itemlist();

      $this->load->view('item/item_edit',$data);
```

}

In which when the user clicks "Edit Item", it will populate the form with the selected row.

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url().'item/edititem' ?> " method="post">
       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">Description</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="description"><?php echo set_value('description'); ?></textarea>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="price">Amount (in pesos)</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">Php</div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price" id="price" placeholder="Amount" value="<?php echo set_value('price'); ?>">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">.00</div>
            </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">EDIT ITEM</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is from model to controller, You can make an array and store that 3 fields. (I assume there is only single row returned by your query since you are using id as where).

```
$result = array();
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    $result['name'] = $row->item_name;
    $result['description'] = $row->item_description;
    $result['price'] = $row->item_price;
}
return $result;
```

You can access it in the controller using:

```
$data['items']['name'];
$data['items']['description']
$data['items']['price']
```

Or in your view as

```
$items['name'];
$items['description'];
$items['price'];
```

Comment: It gives me the error "Message: Undefined variable: data" in the controller

Comment: try this on the line which you are calling the itemList method...

$data = array();
$data['items'] = $this->ItemModel->itemlist();
echo $data['items']['name'];
echo $data['items']['description']
echo $data['items']['price']

Comment: How can i get that $result from model to my controller?

Comment: I already posted the code. Since you are passing the $data into your view. You can access the $result using $items['name'] $items['description']  $items['price'] ...

Comment: Okay, but it still gives me an error:

"Undefined property: Item::$name Filename: core/Model.php Line Number: 77 Backtrace: File: C:\xampp\htdocs\itwa213\application\controllers\Item.php Line: 28 Function: __get "

Comment: What is itemlist() method? Are you sure that is the correct method? Maybe the method is: edititem($this->input->get('id')) .

Answer (score 0):

Your Model:
This may useful if your want to return a specific 1 row without using result()

```
public function edititem($id){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tblitem ');
        $this->db->where('item_id ',$id);
        return $query = $this->db->get()->custom_row_object(0, 'ItemModel');
    }
```

Your Controller: Call the edititem($id) from ItemModel (your model)

```
public function editItem(){
             $item_id=$this->uri->segment(3); //added this
             $this->load->helper('form');
             $this->load->model('ItemModel');
             $item_details=$this->ItemModel->edititem($item_id); //added this

             $data['item_name'] = $item_details->name;
             $data['item_desc'] = $item_details->description;
             $data['item_price'] = $item_details->price;

             //now you can use the specific data to your view.
             $this->load->view('item/item_edit',$data);

        }
```

In your view, you can use the variable like:

```
$item_name;
$item_desc;
$item_price;
```

eg:

```
<input type="text" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $item_name;?>" />
```

Comment: It gives me an error "Call to undefined function get()" on "return $query = $this->db-get()->custom_row_object(0, 'ItemModel');"

EDIT: i corrected the "->" before get, but it still gives me an error: "Undefined property: Item::$name
Filename: core/Model.php

Line Number: 77

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\itwa213\application\controllers\Item.php
Line: 28
Function: __get "

Comment: You should look at your code for the get function you use. try to replace the $this->input->get('id') to real id number first. check whether it success or not. If success by using existed id number, so it should your get function not working or something wrong. i'm seldom use $this->input->get() but $this->input->post().

Comment: on your edit link, you can use <a href="controller/method/id">edit</a>. so the id is the third segment uri. use $this->uri->segment(3); to get the third segment and store into $item_id variable. so, no need to use $this->input->get(); to get the item_id.

Answer (score 0):

Here your model looks like this

```
public function edititem($id){
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tblitem WHERE item_id = "$id"');

  if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $query->row_array();  // row_array return single row and result_array return multiple row
        return $row['dt'];
```

And your controller looks like this

```
public function editItem(){
             $this->load->helper('form');
             $this->load->model('ItemModel');
             $item_details=$this->ItemModel->edititem($this->input->get('id'));
here you use foreach loop 

foreach ($item_details as $key=>$value){
//do this in $data array
}     //now you can use the specific data to your view.
             $this->load->view('item/item_edit',$data);

        }
```